# SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I'm trying to create a list workflow in SharePoint designer 2013. When I click on the OK button it gives me the error.

> Server Side activities have been updated. You need to restart
>   SharePoint Designer to use the updated version of activities.

I have restarted spd, and my computer. Is there anyone else who has run into this issue? Thanks

Comment: you should uninstall workflow manager client 1.0.

Comment: Is this a dead thread? I have the same problem, and have found no solutions anywhere yet. And in line with Bob Elander above, I find the problem is with SP2013 workflows. I do not have workflow manager installed. I've uninstalled and re-installed SPD many times, cleared cache, etc. I've tried everything and I have yet to see any solution to this problem...

Comment: When you create a new workflow choose "SharePoint 2010 Workflow" in "Platform Type"

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling SPDesigner and then removing the following folders.

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer

Reboot and then re-install with the latest version.

This cured it for me, seems to have issues with roaming profiles from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, when I have SPD 2013 x64 installed on my server. I have installed SPD 2013 x32 on a different machine, and I was able to create 2014 workflows. 
I am not sure if moving to a different machine or using another version (32bit vs 64bits) version solved the problem.

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Copy Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.Proxy.dll assembly  to  WebsiteCache folder (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache{Site Name}\15.0.0.4745)

http://www.jrjlee.com/2014/10/server-side-activities-have-been-updated.html

Answer (score 0):

Please

can you upload the file Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.Proxy.dll
to resolve this problem

Comment: This does not answer the question as per the StackExchange standards. Please check [answer]. One-liners qualify for comments.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am late to answer here, but I was facing same problem and i found exact solution, the actual culprit is Workflow client installed with Visual studio. Just uninstall it from Program and Features in control panel

Answer (score 0):

I have suffered the same fate with SPD 2013 and SharePoint online.  None of the suggestions above have worked but when I choose Platform Type: SharePoint 2010 it works fine.  Does not for Platform Type: SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

How to install the SharePoint Designer 2013 latest version.

1. Clearing the cache

   Removed contents from

   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache
    C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
    C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache

   Unchecked "Cache site data across SharePoint Designer sessions" in SPD 
    Application Options

   2. Try uninstalling SPDesigner and then removing the following folders.

      C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer

      • Reboot and then re-install with the latest version in below order.

      Order of installation 1. SharePoint Designer 64-bit ([sharepointdesigner2013_64bit.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35491)) File Version: 15.0.4420.1017

      SharePoint Designer Service Pack 1 ([spdsp2013-kb2817441-fullfile-x64-en-us.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42009)) File Version: 15.0.4569.1506

      Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 ([spd2013-kb2863836-fullfile-x64-glb.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42871) ) File Version: 15.0.4615.1001

      Update for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 ( [spd2013-kb3114337-fullfile-x64-glb.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50708)) File Version: 15.0.4787.1000

      Update for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 ([spd2013-kb3114721-fullfile-x64-glb.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53389)) File Version: 15.0.4849.1000